# FirebaseAuth.instance is null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Hey I'm new to flutter development and I got this message when trying to do SignUp to Firebase

```
I/flutter (23432): NoSuchMethodError: The method 'createUserWithEmailAndPassword' was called on null.
I/flutter (23432): Receiver: null
```

And here is the code

AuthServide.dart

```
class AuthServices {
  static FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  static Future<SignInSignUpResult> signUp(String email, String password,
      String name, List<String> selectedGenres, String selectedLanguage) async {
    try {
      log(_auth.toString());
      log("Proses Sign Up");
      UserCredential result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      log("Selesai Sign Up");
      log(result.toString());
      Users user = result.user.convertToUser(
          name: name,
          selectedGenres: selectedGenres,
          selectedLanguage: selectedLanguage);
      await UserServices.updateUser(user);

      return SignInSignUpResult(user: user);
    } catch (e) {
      return SignInSignUpResult(message: e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

After I check the log I know that FirebaseAuth.instance is null, but why?

I'm currently following a tutorial on an online flutter class and I got stuck here.

Anybody can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Did you import? `import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';` as explained in [the doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/)?

Comment: @Kato Yes, I've import firebae_auth package

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I think it will work for you. Make sure you added the firebase auth pakage `firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1`

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthMethods {

  //  CONDITION ? TRUE: FLASE
  User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null ? User(userId: user.uid) : null;
  }

  Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
    AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password);
  FirebaseUser firebaseUser = result.user;
    return _userFromFirebaseUser(firebaseUser);
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
}
  }

    try {
  AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password);
  FirebaseUser firebaseUser = result.user;
  return _userFromFirebaseUser(firebaseUser);
 } catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
}
  }
 Future resetPass(String email) async {
try {
     return await _auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
}
}

Future signOut() async {
try {
  return await _auth.signOut();
} catch (e) {}
  }
}
```